# Изменение стилей CSS средствами Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите в чем проблема: Класс у элемента меняется только на время выполнения функции, после чего устанавливается такой как был. Мне нужно чтоб после выполнения showPage className оставался 'show'.

```
function showPage (){ 
  var page = document.getElementById('test');
  page.className = 'show'; 
}
```

Comment: очевидно, проблема не в этом коде, ещё хотелось бы узнать как вы определяете состояние DOM на "время выполнения функции"

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/t2Ba6/

Comment: @Freest: http://jsfiddle.net/vGpTc/ — ЧЯДНТ?

---
@eicto: опередили.

Comment: Все. Вопрос решен. Проблема была в том что я onClick на ссылку повесил. С кнопкой все работает без проблем. 
Состояние DOM проверял Fifebug-ом.
Всем спасибо.

Comment: click можно и на ссылку вешать, в конце return false...

Comment: @eicto Спасибо!